# FMX how to cast Tbutton and assigning it with Tag in TAction / TActionList?

Tags: delphi, taction

I have **TButton**(s) associated to the same action **TAction** and When they are clicked, the action execute method declared.
Now i want to cast the Sender parameter in the actions **OnExecute**/**OnUpdate** instruction to show which Button was clicked.

what i did :

```
procedure TMainForm.ActListViewUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (sender is TAction) then
  begin
    case (Sender as TButton).Tag of
      1: ShowMessage(inttostr((sender as Tbutton).tag ));
      2: ShowMessage(inttostr((sender as Tbutton).tag ));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Doesn't work. Could you point me to the right way?

Comment: I haven't used actions a lot, but your code is clearly incorrect, as the `if` checks for the sender being a `TAction` but the `case` statement then treats the sender as being a `TButton`.   Looking at the help of `TAction`, I'd suggest that you should be using `TButton(TAction(Sender).ActionComponent).Tag` in your 'case' statement.

Comment: It is typically not interesting to know which component triggered an action. But if you insist ( ;) ) look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302748/how-can-i-see-who-triggered-an-action-in-delphi?rq=1 which also makes your question a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @philip-j-rayment i tried `TButton(TAction(Sender).ActionComponent).Tag` it doen't work for me. 
@tom-brunberg uuh i saw, but i want to store differents value inside Text property of each `TButton`.

Comment: `ShowMessage( (Sender as TAction).ActionComponent.Name );` works well for me.